# How to show multiple values in datagridview cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am unware the fact that whether it is possible to show different values from access table to a single datagridview cell.
For example.
If table xyz contain data like this

> col1 col2 col3 col4 Col5
>
> B1 P1 P1 P2 P1/P1
>
> B2 P1 P2 P3
>
> B3 P1 P2 P3 B4
>
> P2 P2 P3 P2/P2

I hope I am clear what I want to know?
If this is possible how can I achieve this?

Regards to all.

Comment: select B1+ +P1+ +P2 as col1 ?  concatenate them

Answer (score 0):

if you want only show data then you need to convert `ToString` and then concatenate values of the wanted columns.

Just create a query where you do this(`Access query`):

```
SELECT col1
, col2
, col3
, col4
, CStr(col2) + '/' + CStr(col3) AS col5
FROM yourTable
```